# What is the right way to bind Highcharts event in React functional Component?

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts

I am using highcharts in react with react highchart:
[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-highchart-jjzjx118-6vef8y)
I defined the chart option in another file and import it as a state

```
import * as options from "./chartConfig";
const [option, setOption] = useState(options.option_bubble);
```

and now change the option in useEffect,why I have to do it in react component is because I need to do further things like fetch data so I can't just define it in the chartConfig.js.

Now mycode is like:

```
export default function HighChart(props) {
  const [state1, setState1] = useState("button");
  const [option, setOption] = useState(options.option_bubble);
  const [refreshTrigger, setRefreshTrigger] = useState(0);

  const clickChart = event => {
    console.log("event", event.point);
  };


  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect");

     option.plotOptions.series.point.events.click = clickChart;
     let NewOptoin = Object.assign({}, option);
     setOption(NewOptoin);
     setRefreshTrigger(Math.random);
  },[props]);
```

so I want to bind the render() inside react component. in pure js it looks like this:

```
console.log(Highcharts.chart);
Highcharts.chart('container', {
 chart: {
    type: "bubble",
    plotBorderWidth: 1,
    events: {
        render() {
        let chart = this;

        chart.series[0].points.forEach(p => {
                    let labelWidth = p.marker.width,
                dataLabel = p.dataLabel,
              padding = 2;

             dataLabel.css({
                    width: labelWidth
             })
            if (isFirstRender){
           ÏdataLabel.translate(dataLabel.alignAttr.x + dataLabel.getBBox().width / 2 - padding, dataLabel.alignAttr.y)
isFirstRender = false;
            }   
        })
      }
    }
  },
```

so what render function is in the events object, why it is not looks like:

```
events:{
render:function(){
 }
}
```

and how can I re-define it in react ?

Comment: Hi @jjzjx118_2, What is your exact problem? Do you want to add `render` event callback function or overwrite it?

Comment: Hi  @ppotaczek I want to overwrite it . as you see the demo is use pure js. but I use react component. so I need to assign a function to overwrite render() inside a react component . like this:chartRef.current.chart. events.render = function myOwnFunction(){...} , but you must noticed there is no key for render() in the demo code. I need a key to assign new function to handle render()

Comment: But `render() { ... }` is only a shortened notation of `render: function() { ... }`. I do not think that you need to overwrite that function. If you need double context, you can use IIFE function, like in this example: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-6ez18